# How to indicate two html sections are continuation of each other

Tags: html, wai-aria, narrator

Are there any attributes or is there a way to indicate that two sections are a continuation of each other. Example below:

```
<section id="section-top">
    <div>Item 1 </div>
    <div>Item 2 </div>
</section>
<section id="section-bottom">
    <div>Item 3 </div>
    <div>Item 4 </div>
</section>
```

I need to keep things in separate sections because section-bottom is hidden until an expanding button is pressed. So when it displays, i need to indicate that its a part of the first list so that narrator reads 3/4 when you arrow down into item three instead of 1/2 because its in a separate section.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of your example HTML is not semantically correct, that said you can use [`aria`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wai-aria/info) roles and attributes to expose the intended meaning to screen-readers.

---

## Markup

```
<section aria-label="Group of things">
  <div role="list">
    <section role="none presentation" id="section-top"> 
      <div role="listitem">
        <p>Thing 1</p>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem">
        <p>Thing 2</p>
      </div>
    </section> 
    <section role="none presentation" id="section-bottom"> 
      <div role="listitem" hidden>
        <p>Thing 3</p>
      </div>
      <div role="listitem" hidden>
        <p>Thing 4</p>
      </div>
    </section> 
  </div>
</section>
```

### Explanation

- Wrap your original `<section>` elements in a `<div>` with [`role=list`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#list).

  > Lists contain children whose role is listitem, or elements whose role is group which in turn contains children whose role is listitem.
- Wrap the `<div>` with `role=list` inside another `<section>` element, and use the `aria-label` attribute to transform it into a region, and give it an accessible name.

  > `<section>`, region when it has an accessible name using aria-labelledby, aria-label or title attribute.
- Your original `<section>` elements have been given the [`role=presentation`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#presentation) to negate the implicit role semantics but not affect the contents.
- Your original `<div>` elements have been given [`role=listitem`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#listitem).

  > Authors ***MUST*** ensure elements with `role=listitem` are contained in, or owned by, an element with the role list or group.
- Your initially hidden other elements have been given the [`hidden`](http://w3c.github.io/html/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) attribute, and you will need to follow up yourself with the useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868089/how-to-indicate-two-html-sections-are-continuation-of-each-other/51868317#51868317) from [codeMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4009972/codemonkey) on how you show/hide these.

  > "…because section-bottom is hidden until an expanding button is pressed."

Comment: A few tweaks.  The first `<section>` element is a landmark by default and should have a label instead of a tooltip.  Use the `aria-label` attribute instead of `title`.  The inner sections have two roles and should only have `role="presentation"`.  Was the desire of the OP to have list items?

Comment: Thanks @slugolicious, with aria it's always great to have another opinion.

I have amended the wrapping `<section>` to use `aria-label=` instead of `title=`.

I was [following this note](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role-presentation-note-none) in my answer to using the two roles, is this still practical advice?

Going on this specific detail of OP's question formed my logic for using `list` and `listitem` roles, this way it would read out 1 of 4 etc.

_i need to indicate that its a part of the first list so that narrator reads 3/4 when you arrow down into item three instead of 1/2_

Comment: Yes! this is what I needed! thank you! The only issue I have now is that narrator reads "[item name] one of n level 1" is there a way to prevent narrator from reading the level?

Comment: @shannon, yes the spec does let you use two roles with the fallback option.  i have never seen anyone do it, though.  all accessibility sme's that i know just use `role="presentation"`.

Comment: @gema did you try the solution with jaws or nvda?  it might be that narrator reads lists that way, saying "level", but that would be weird.  are you using `aria-level`?

Comment: @slugolicious I will try with the others to see what it says, and no not using aria-level

Answer (score 0):

Plain HTML doesn’t offer a way to convey that one element is the continuation of another element.

I would argue that you should use only one `section` element, and as many `div` elements as needed for grouping the content inside that `section`.

```html
<section>
  <div class="section-top">
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <p>Item 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="section-bottom" hidden>
    <p>Item 3</p>
    <p>Item 4</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

As the `div` element isn’t a sectioning element, it doesn’t separate your content; all of it is part of the same `section`.